# Laravel doesn't running my route

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, migrate, laravel-artisan

I'm beginner in Laravel 5. I created a model(Cars), a controller(CarController) and a view(show.blade.php). But, everytime that I try to execute my project, I get the same error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

These are my codes:

Car.php (Model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    //
}
```

2016_07_30_135543_create_cars_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCarsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('make');
            $table->string('model');
            $table->date('produced_on');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('cars');
    }
}
```

CarController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Car;

class CarController extends Controller
{
    //
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $car = Car::find($id);
        return view('cars.show', array('car' => $car));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

show.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Car {{ $car->id }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Car {{ $car->id }}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Make: {{ $car->make }}</li>
      <li>Model: {{ $car->model }}</li>
      <li>Produced on: {{ $car->produced_on }}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

routes.php

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('cars', 'CarController');
```

I try: localhost:8000/laravel/public/cars
localhost:8000/laravel/public/cars.show
localhost:8000/laravel/public/show

I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just `localhost:8000/cars` :D

Comment: I think you have posted the whole project here Hhahaha !

Comment: xD Ismail RBOUH, I did as you suggested. But now, there's nothing in the page. No HTML :(

Comment: You ran the server via `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: Yes try to return something in your `index()`, example: `return "Hello Cássia";` !

Comment: If you want to access `show()` method try : `localhost:8000/cars/1` where 1 is your car ID !

Comment: localhost:8000/cars/1, I have this: InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [cars.show] not found.

Comment: Okey put `show.blade.php` in a folder called  `cars` under the `views` directory!

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I'm so happy :)

Answer (score 0):

try one of these:

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/cars
```

OR serve your application via `artisan` command first

```
php artisan serve
```

browse like this

`http://localhost:8000/cars`